# how to remove array item from the list javascript

Tags: javascript

How to remove selected item and nested item too from array using javascript

```
const data =  [
    {id: 1, name: 'Gill'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Gill2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Gill3'},
  {id: 4, name: 'Gill4'},
  {id: 5, name: 'Gill5'}
]
```

my tried code is

https://jsfiddle.net/p5fxhcbk/2/

Thanks

if i pass strong text console.log(filterID("4", data))

then output should be

```
[
    {id: 1, name: 'Gill'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Gill2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Gill3'}
]
```

id 4 and 5 will be removed and so on if anything came after 4

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Please include the code in your question (using the "Edit" link). That said, your function returns `data[i]` while it is actually working on the variable `arr`. I think you meant to write `return arr;`? but you have other problems in your function it seems, sucha as returning too early, using `splice` on the param which will affect `data` by reference, etc

Comment: @Reyno it does make sense can we write recursive function for this ?

Comment: Your question seems unclear to me, in your example you have no nested items, and the result you ask for doesn't match your description and code

Answer (score 1):

According to your explanation, you are looking for something that the node you pass in argument, the next to that elements will not get displayed. So if you pass 4 the 3 elements get displayed and like wise,

```
const data =  [
  {id: 1, name: 'Gill'},
  {id: 2, name: 'Gill2'},
  {id: 3, name: 'Gill3'},
  {id: 6, name: 'Gill4'},
  {id: 7, name: 'Gill5'}
]

function filterOut(arr, removeFromNode) {
    const arrD = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i].id < removeFromNode) {
            arrD.push(data[i]);
        }
    }
    return arrD;
}

console.log(filterOut(data, 6))
```

Comment: This doesn't look like a robust solution, it assumes that the index in the array will always be the id - 1. The OP seems to want to filter on the id, not on the index. It may look as a working answer, but by experience this code will start to fail easily when the assumption becomes false

Comment: Yes @Kaddath Agreed, I tried by changing the passed id from 4 to 6, so for that I am updating my answer.